# Change data in an IQueryable object

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have an `IQueryable` object like this

```
var persons = from m in db.Persons
              select m;
```

The returned fields will be: `name: String`, `family: String`, `cityID: Int` in it. I have another `IQueryable` object that get `cityID: Int` and `CityName: String` from another table like one here:

```
var citys = from x in db.CitysInfo
            select x;
```

Now I want an `IQueryable` object that have `name: String`, `family: String`, `CityName: String`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a join and project to an anonymous class:

```
var results = from p in db.Persons 
              join c in db.CitysInfo on p.cityID equals c.cityId
              select new 
              {
                name = p.name,
                family = p.family,
                CityName = c.CityName,
              }
```